# animate list items left and right

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, styling

I have a little image slideshow with 8 picture, but only show 5 picture, the others are hidden.

This is the html

```
<div id="itemsListBox">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/washing_machine.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/refrigerator.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/dishwasher.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/ovens_stoves_hobs.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/extractors.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/microwave_oven.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/coffee_makers.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/washer_dryer.png" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/home-items/tumble_dryer.png" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#itemsListBox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#itemsListBox ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#itemsListBox ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 18%;
    margin: 1%;
}
#itemsListBox ul li img {
    width: 100%;    
}
```

I can move the image with this code:

```
$("#rightArrow").click(function(e) {
        var curr =  $("#itemsListBox ul li:last");
        curr.parent().prepend(curr);
    });
$("#leftArrow").click(function(e) {
        var curr =  $("#itemsListBox ul li:first");
        curr.parent().append(curr);
    });
```

But i want to do this with something animation. Any idea?

Here is a live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bergkamp/shnyH/

Comment: Please be more specific than "something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Try something like :

Set your Image Position as relative in your css :

```
 img {position:relative;}
```

and Instead of append and prepend use animate function of Jquery to change the left position.

```
   $("img").animate({ 
    left: "-=150px",
  }, "slow" );
```

see Edited Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/z3PzC/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a slide down/slide up animation using your images : http://jsfiddle.net/Jag96/5VDTL/

The main hurdle here is that you are hiding a few images, only showing 5 at a time, so you need to animate on the first and 5th li element:

```
$("#itemsListBox ul li:nth-child(5)").slideUp("slow", function () {
    curr.hide().prependTo(curr.parent()).slideDown();
});
```

You can also use the jQuery .animate() method if you want more customization of your animations.